# Flip only one axis of a transformation matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

A 4x4 transformation matrix can be multiply to transform a point by translating and rotating it. I have a transformation matrix, however I noticed that the X translation is going to the opposite way of what I want, and rotation in the YZ plane (rotate about X axis) is going to the opposite direction (e.g. CCW instead of CW) of what I want. The rest is ok.

So I thought the solution for both problem is to flip only the X axis of this transformation matrix somehow. Any way to process this matrix so X axis will be flipped?

From what I guess I need to do an axis flip X, then multiply the matrix I have, then do the flip again? If that is so, is the flip X and the resulting matrix looks like this?

[image]

I tried this, but the result in my program looks wrong so I don't think this is the correct solution. Of course adding minus sign to the 4th element of this matrix did the trick of fixing X translation for me correctly but not the rotation. So I thought flipping the axis itself should take care of this problem.